# For my code below,i have explicitly declared the exceptional situation i'm going to raise(using throws),Still my code shows an Error,why is it?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
public class NullPointerExceptionExample1 {
public static void main(String... args)throws NullPointerException {
    String s=new String("Hello");
    s=null;
    System.out.println(s.length());
}
}
```

I'm Intentionally trying to raise a NullPointerException,and i have indicated the exceptional situation i'm going to raise using (throws NullPointerException).But still my code shows an error(NullPointerException)

Comment: That was actually a typo!!

Comment: NPE is unchecked exception. if you want to catch, wrap it in try-catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you declare your method as `throws NullPointerException` means that it can throw that exception. In this particular case it's meaningless, since `NullPointerException` is an unchecked exception (it's a sub-class of `RuntimeException` and can be thrown by your method even without having that throws clause).

Anyway, declaring an exception in a throws clause doesn't prevent it from being thrown and doesn't catch it, so I don't see why you expect the `NullPointerException` not to be thrown. `s.length` would always throw a `NullPointerException` when `s` is null.

Answer (score 1):

(1) It's unnecessary to specify any runtime exception (such as `NullPointerException`) in a `throws` clause.

(2) A `throws` clause is simply a warning that the method may throw the exception; it doesn't magically make the error that triggers the exception go away. You're trying to call `.length()` on a null reference, so you get an exception; what do you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a try/catch combo. The fact that you stated `throws NullPointerException` doesn't mean that no exception will occur you are just letting any calling objects know that this type of error can occur and should handle it. Here is a try/catch.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.io.IOException;

public class NullPointerExceptionExample1 { 

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String s=new String("Hello");
        s=null;
        try{
            System.out.println(s.length());
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            // handle error here
            System.out.println("Caught NullPointerException");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: But when i explicitly declare a IOException,even if the exception raises , it doesnt show any error,why is it so? Does it have something to do with checked and uncheckedExceptions?